# How to create an 'Acess token' via Artifactory REST API?

Tags: access-token, docker-desktop, jfrog-xray

my company uses Docker Desktop and we want to use this cool JFrog extension:
https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-docker-desktop-extension

We also have an JFrog XRay server, so all pre-requisites are fullfilled.

In order to establish a connection, I need to provide a so called 'access token' (AND NOT 'identity token') to the extension.
Does someone know how to create such an 'access token' via REST API?
All what I found deal with 'identity token'....

Best Valentin

I am expecting a simple http request with curl or whatever to generate such a personal access token.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
POST <your platform url>/access/api/v1/tokens
```

example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <valid access token>" -XPOST "http://localhost:8082/access/api/v1/tokens" -d "scope=applied-permissions/user"
```

For more information, you can take a look at the [documentation here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-CreateToken).

Comment: Thanks @YuvalOhayon .. but one problem remains. I do not have an 'access token' so far, so what can I provide as <valid access token>???

Comment: You can always create the first one via the UI under Administration -> User Management -> Generate Token

Answer (score 0):

To generate an access token via a REST API, use the below cURL command:-

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <valid access token>" -XPOST "https://<ART-URL>/access/api/v1/tokens" -d "scope=applied-permissions/user"
```

The above command will generate an access token and we can use this for configuring our docker-desktop extension.
For more information regarding access tokens please refer to the [Access Tokens](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-AccessTokens) documentation.